# Check box value not saving in PHP (Codeigniter)

Tags: php, codeigniter, checkbox

After the validation of a form, I gather the following info.

```
$inscription_parent['tempassword'] = $this->input->post('password');
$inscription_parent['matchingPassword'] = $this->input->post('matchingPassword');
$inscription_parent['nameUser'] = $this->input->post('nameUser');
$inscription_parent['firstNameUser'] = $this->input->post('firstNameUser');
$inscription_parent['sexUser'] = $this->input->post('sexUser');
$inscription_parent['emailUser'] = $this->input->post('emailUser');
$inscription_parent['phoneHomeUser'] = $this->input->post('phoneHomeUser');
$inscription_parent['phoneCellUser'] = $this->input->post('phoneCellUser');
$inscription_parent['phoneWorkUser'] = $this->input->post('phoneWorkUser');
$inscription_parent['workUser'] = $this->input->post('workUser');
$inscription_parent['chkAnimation'] = $this->input->post('chkAnimation');
$inscription_parent['chkGestion'] = $this->input->post('chkGestion');
$inscription_parent['chkAccompagnement'] = $this->input->post('chkAccompagnement');
$inscription_parent['chkCouture'] = $this->input->post('chkCouture');
$inscription_parent['chkCuisine'] = $this->input->post('chkCuisine');
$inscription_parent['chkAutre'] = $this->input->post('chkAutre');
$inscription_parent['autreImplication'] = $this->input->post('autreImplication');

$this->session->set_userdata($inscription_parent);
```

As you might have noticed, the chk-named variables are variables. Their default values are as follows:-

```
<input id="chkAnimation" name="chkAnimation" class="element checkbox" type="checkbox" value="1" />
<label class="choice" for="chkAnimation">Animation</label>
<input id="chkGestion" name="chkGestion" class="element checkbox" type="checkbox" value="2" />
<label class="choice" for="chkGestion">Gestion/Comptabilité</label>
<input id="chkAccompagnement" name="chkAccompagnement" class="element checkbox" type="checkbox" value="3" />
<label class="choice" for="chkAccompagnement">Accompagnement (sorties)</label>
<input id="chkCouture" name="chkCouture" class="element checkbox" type="checkbox" value="4" />
<label class="choice" for="chkCouture">Couture, costumes</label>
<input id="chkCuisine" name="chkCuisine" class="element checkbox" type="checkbox" value="5"/>
<label class="choice" for="chkCuisine">Cuisine (cuistot)</label>
<input id="chkAutre" name="chkAutre" class="element checkbox" type="checkbox" value="6"/>
<label class="choice" for="chkAutre">Autre</label>
```

When I print the content of the array after the submit operation, everything is stored properly, but not the checkboxes! It doesnt matter which one I check or uncheck, this will all have :

```
(chk(variable)=> )
```

Can you help ?

By the way, they are within the form tags.

Comment: The code you posted will work fine as is, however I think you must be doing something wrong around the form validation before that bit of code.. Can you post your form validation code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was situated in the code around the array filling, which caused it to be overwritted. Thanks for the tips anyway.